# navigation bar centering an element next to floated right elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

[image] of my navigation bar.

I'm trying to center a link in the middle of my `navbar`. I've been looking around for a solution but it just breaks my `navbar`, i.e. moves the link by a few pixels to the right. I know if I put `display: block` it will center it but my items on the right get bumped off. This is what I have so far:

```css
.navbar > a.favmovies-title {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", Charcoal, "Helvetica Inserat", "Bitstream Vera Sans Bold", "Arial Black", "sans serif";
  font-size: 155%;
  width: 25%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: orange;
}

.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FF6347;
  padding: 1%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar > ul > li.right {
  float: right;
}

.navbar > ul > li > a.userlogin {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="favmovies-title" href="/movies/find_top_rating/1">FavMovies</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="right"><a class="userlogin" href="/users/sign_in">Login</a><span class = "small_font_size"></span></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="userlogin" href="/users/sign_up">Signup</a></li>
    <input class="right" id="Search-Bar" type="text">
    <li class="right" id="Search">search <img src="/assets/icons/searchicon.fw.png" alt="Search" id="SearchIcon"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've been trying some display flex properties and transformations but it's not working. The aligned-content property didn't help me either. Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try absolutely positioning your logo in the middle of your navbar.

Try adding this to your text logo styles:

```
.navbar > a.favmovies-title {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Only downside: the logo img will look blurry in most screen widths, because of the transform...

Comment: @Savado if this does cause issues, then `transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0);` can sometimes fix this

Comment: @Brett East Great tip! Tiny correction on my previous comment: the logo is no img but just plain text. (The blurry effect also happens with plain text though)

Comment: @shakespeare no worries mate, if it works for you I would love an upvote and 'accepted' on my answer

Comment: Would love some feedback on why this answer was down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

You could center the logo normally by using `text-align: center` on the `.navbar` and make the floating `ul` element `position: absolute` to make this happen.

```
.navbar {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep this worked. Much appreciated. Still learning about centering stuff and when to use position: absolute and relative. Thanks man!